# How to set compiler in eclipse to use borland C++ Builder 3?

Tags: c++, eclipse, refactoring, c++builder, borland-c++

I know this is a pretty strange question, but I have new project that I have to refactor a code that was written long time ago using Borland C++ Builder version 3.0
It is almost impossible to refactor and use that IDE to keep track of refactoring. I am not sure if it possible but I want to see if I can use Eclipse and set the Eclipse to use Borland C++ Builder as the compiler.

Please let me know if there is any IDE that can help me. Also please do not give answers like, why using Borland C++ Builder or rewrite the code.

I will appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Borland C++ Builder was released in 1991. You should seriously just use a modern compiler and rewrite the code to compile with it.

Comment: `and use that IDE to keep track of refactoring`  Very few programmers use IDE's to "keep track of refactoring".   Heck, I'm not even sure what you mean by "keep track of refactoring" -- you make a change, you test the change.   Anyway, what about just using a good source control system like SVN or similar?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think they mean using the built in refactoring tools for tasks such as renaming variables and extracting methods.

Comment: Thank you guys for reply! @PaulMcKenzie well sjdowling answered it very well.

Comment: As I said I cannot change the compiler because the project cannot be compile using other compilers! So I need to find an IDE that can use bcc32.exe as it's compiler. And I cannot rewrite the project because customer doesn't want it!

Comment: Also for tracking of the changes, we are using GitHub which tracks all changes. I just need an IDE that gives refactoring features and can use Borland Compiler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++Builder 3 did not support refactoring.  That was added in C++Builder 2006 (but is very limited compared to the refactorings available to Delphi, which uses the same IDE).

It is possible to configure Eclipse to invoke a custom C++ toolchain.  C++Builder 3 has a command-line compiler, **bcc32.exe**, and a command-line linker, **ilink32.exe**.